# Using msgs from the same package

Tags: ros, package, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to use msgs from the current package.
So usually it's like this, when I'm using a different package:

```
#include package_name/msg_name
pub_ = nh_.advertise<project_name::msg_name>("topic", 1);
```

But I'm trying to use the msg I created in the same project package
Let's say my package name is first_package and msg is first_msg, but doing so:

```
#include first_package/first_msg
pub_ = nh_.advertise<first_project::first_msg>("topic", 1);
```

Doesnt seem to work. Well why should I import something that is already in my package. What is the correct syntax here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209228/using-msgs-from-the-same-package/) by [RosFan19](https://answers.ros.org/users/21450/rosfan19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2015-05-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-15**:
It is always a good idea to include verbatim any error messages or warnings that you receive. Just stating that *it doesn't work* is making it really difficult for us to help you.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-15**:
Also: for almost all msg pkgs, the `package_name` is used as the namespace for the messages, so in your example `package_name` and `project_name` should probably be identical?

**Comment by [Reiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22377/reiner/) on 2015-06-02**:
I know, it's not a big help, but it may be worthwhile to move your message definition to a separate package (see ros best practices).
Also, try simply copying the tutorial (see tutorials understanding topics) and analysing the differences, helps me usually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is your #include in the following form with the triangular braces and *.h?

```
#include <first_package/first_msg.h>
```

Are you getting an error in the compiling process? If so, what type of error?

Another issue might be the generate/add messages components of your CMakeLists.txt

---

Originally posted by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) with karma: 327 on 2015-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0